# For loop to identify a missing variable and create dummy rows in Python

Tags: pandas, for-loop, dummy-variable

I have data frame with two columns

1. Registration number of vehicle
2. KM Service Done

There are 25,000+ vehicles with different registration numbers.
These vehicles have availed different services ranging from 10,000 km to 800,000 km.

Vehicle 1 has availed services 10,000km, 20,000km, 70,000km

[Services Missed : 30,000km, 40,000km, 50,000km, 60,000km]

Vehicle 2 has availed services 210,000km, 220,000km 230,000km, 250,000km

[Services Missed : 240,000 km]
and so on...

Requirement

For loop to identify which services are missed for a particular vehicle
and to create a dummy row with registration number, km service and a third column which specified service availed or service missed.

Here is a sample data

Registration Number KM Service Done

HY12TN2345  10000

HY12TN2345  20000

HY12TN2345  70000

JO78UI4675  210000

JO78UI4675  220000

JO78UI4675  230000

JO78UI4675  250000

RT09EW0764  80000

RT09EW0764  90000

RT09EW0764  100000

RT09EW0764  110000

RT09EW0764  150000

RT09EW0764  160000

RT09EW0764  170000

RT09EW0764  180000

EQ21IT3040  410000

EQ21IT3040  510000

Output would look something like this
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipHcN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) on series:

```
# get all possible values
all_services = df['KMServiceDone'].unique()

def reindex_grp(grp):
    s = grp.set_index('KMServiceDone')
    # add dummy rows for missing KMServiceDone
    s = s.reindex(all_services)
    return s.reset_index()
    
# apply function on each group
dfx = (df
      .groupby('RegistrationNumber', as_index=False)
      .apply(reindex_grp)
      .reset_index(drop=True))

# create status column
dfx['service_status'] = np.where(dfx['RegistrationNumber'].isna(),
                                 'Missed', 
                                 'Availed')

print(dfx.head(20))

    KMServiceDone RegistrationNumber service_status
0           10000                NaN         Missed
1           20000                NaN         Missed
2           70000                NaN         Missed
3          210000                NaN         Missed
4          220000                NaN         Missed
5          230000                NaN         Missed
6          250000                NaN         Missed
7           80000                NaN         Missed
8           90000                NaN         Missed
9          100000                NaN         Missed
10         110000                NaN         Missed
11         150000                NaN         Missed
12         160000                NaN         Missed
13         170000                NaN         Missed
14         180000                NaN         Missed
15         410000         EQ21IT3040        Availed
16         510000         EQ21IT3040        Availed
17          10000         HY12TN2345        Availed
18          20000         HY12TN2345        Availed
19          70000         HY12TN2345        Availed
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reindex & np.arange

```
df = (df.assign(Status="service_status")
.set_index("KMServiceDone")
.groupby("RegistrationNumber")["Status"]
.apply(lambda d: d.reindex(np.arange(min(d.index), max(d.index)+delta, delta)))
.reset_index()
.fillna("Missed"))

print (df)
```